# React Native List View Section Header not on top of list?

Tags: listview, reactjs, react-native, sections

It seems that the section header of a list view does not stick at the very top of the list view, but rather about 20 pixels lower.
When you scroll the list it looks very ugly that the rows scroll up higher than the sticky section header.

Is there a fix, a workaround or anything I can do to fix that?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, turns out there is a property that will fix the additional offset on the top of the ListView component:

`automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}`

From what I understand the Content Insets is part a few components to offset the existance of the navigator at the top. But in many cases that offset is just not wanted.